# Check the length of typed chars in WYSIWYG

Tags: php, javascript, wysiwyg

In my site if use textarea + WSYWWYG (Wyzz WYSIWYG).

I would like to minimise and maximise the chars what the user typed. (for ex. min 100 max 1000).

After i post the form, i check the lengt of the posted field. `(strln($_POST['text'..)`
 But the WSYWYG editors post the field in HTML formatted so if the user type:fg then the length will be 9 `(<P>fg</P>9).`

**Could someone suggest me anything how can i check the real length of the typed string?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way, even if it won't give a perfect result, would be to remove the HTML tags from the input, before calling `strlen`.

This can be done using the [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip_tags) function :

> This function tries to return a string
>   with all HTML and PHP tags stripped
>   from a given str .

So, a portion of code such as this one could help :

```
$html = $_POST['text'];
$stripped = strip_tags($html);
$length_noHtml = strlen($stripped);
if ($length_noHtml >= 100 && $length_noHtml <= 1000) {
    // OK
} else  {
    // Not OK
}
```

As a sidenote, if you are using some multi-byte encoding *(I'm thinking about UTF-8)* for your application, you might want to use the [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/mb_strlen) function, instead of [`strlen`](http://php.net/strlen) :

- `strlen` will count the number of bytes in your string
- while `mb_strlen` will count the number of characters.

Comment: its not a bad idea, but with latin chars not a good solution. For a latin char like: ü count 2. Any idea?